Heard a song at church and can't find it
The refrain is: "I am desperately in need, I am falling at your feet, and I plead for mercy." Something like that. I don't know the rest and what I wrote may be out of order.

This one perhaps (top result in Google)? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUCVJFwwns8

Nope, come across that one so many times. Definitely not what I'm looking for, though.

It would help if you could provide other attributes of the song such as YEAR, artist, record label, or a snippet of the melody (by providing some of the notes such as "C | F A F | A G | F D | C" for the beginning of Amazing grace notated in F major ('|'  (pipe) = barline).  I did find a candidate with the first line "In desperate need of mercy" and last line "So please, hear my humble plea" which are repeated, though technically not a refrain: Save Me (Gateway Music, 2008), lyrics here.

Nope, sorry my question is vague. I just heard it in church. The refrain caught me. I love the song but I'm not a musician. I'm not exactly sure of the chord progressions, etc..

@Spitz have you thought of asking the church's worship leader?  Also, many churches livestream their services.  Can you find one from that church that features the song so you can provide a link, although I'm that case they usually display the title and the copyright at the end of the song?

I should check if the church livestreams one of its masses.  I don't think so, though.  There isn't any video equipment at mass.  I have been thinking about asking the music director the next time I go to church, I don't want to bother him with a phone call.  Thanks for the advice @GratefulDisciple

@Spitz The Amazing Grace example was not the chord progression, but the melody.  You can try to find the notes of the melody in a keyboard / piano then write it down.  Or (if you're not shy) you can record it while you sing, upload the sound file somewhere, and link it.  Then someone like me can transcribe it for you and add the notes to the OP, and then someone else can use tools on the Internet for searching songs by notes.  There's even a tool like Midomi to search by humming, although I don't know how complete the database is.

@Spitz You mention mass.  What's the church's denomination?  Another way is to consult their hymn book.  For Catholics, a popular one today is the Breaking Bread Hymnal, maybe perusing the hymnal in Hymnary.org can yield the answer.

Heard a song at church and can't find it?
It may possibly be Falling at Your Feet.
Here is the YouTube Video of this song: ”Falling at Your Feet!”
I’m falling at your feet....

No, that's not it. I've come across it as well. Despite it being a to choice it's not what I'm looking for.

Perhaps St. Bernard's Memorare prayer:

Remember, O most gracious Virgin Mary, that never was it known that
any one who fled to thy protection, implored thy help, and sought thy
intercession was left unaided. Inspired with this confidence, I fly
unto thee, Virgin of virgins, my Mother; to thee I come, before thee I
stand sinful and sorrowful. O Mother of the Word Incarnate, despise
not my petitions; but in thy clemency hear and answer me. Amen.

